# how to sequence a slideIn, fadeIn and a fadeIn one after another?

Tags: jquery

I need to slide down a line and fadeIn 2 items, one after another. I tried writing this code, but it isn't working...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".verticalline").slideDown(2500,"linear",function(){
        $("#iwanimate").fadeIn(1000)
    },function(){
        $(".projects").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".company").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing two functions to [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) which is not valid, you need to pass the second function to [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".verticalline").slideDown(2500,"linear",function(){
        $("#iwanimate").fadeIn(1000,function(){
            $(".projects").fadeIn(1000);
            $(".company").fadeIn(1000);
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `callback` of `fadein`

like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".verticalline").slideDown(2500,"linear",function(){
        $("#iwanimate").fadeIn(1000)
    },function(){
        $(".projects").fadeIn(1000,function(){// use callback function here
              $(".company").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try callbacks after each event. And try adding .delay after each event if you have any further problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".verticalline").slideDown(2500,"linear",function(){

   $("#iwanimate").fadeIn(1000, function()
   {
      $(".projects").fadeIn(1000, function()
      { 
         $(".company").fadeIn(1000);
      });

   });

});
});
```